# The ID element doesnot display

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Web development and Phonegap/Cordova. In the code below i am anticipating that the table would be filed with the version, uuid etc but i am getting an empty column for that.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Phone Gap </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.getElementById("deviceName").innerHtml=device.name;
    document.getElementById("version").innerHtml=device.cordova;
    document.getElementById("uuid").innerHtml=device.uuid;
}

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
    <h1>Device Info </h1>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Device Name</td>
            <td id="deviceName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Version</td>
            <td id="version"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>UUID</td>
            <td id="uuid"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's innerHTML not innerHtml.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.getElementById("deviceName").innerHTML=device.name;
    document.getElementById("version").innerHTML=device.cordova;
    document.getElementById("uuid").innerHTML=device.uuid;
}
```